# Angular Two way binding for standard JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Actually i want to make below JSON Two way binding in angular.

I am using the directive and Factory to bind the control(like TextField, AutomComplete, NumericTextBox..etc) dynamically.

Actually i tried many ways to bind the ng-model to control . it's not working. So please advice how to achieve this.

Source JSON

```
scope.sodata = JSON.parse (
{
  "Data": {
    "entityinfo": {
      "entity": "Customer29Jan16",
      "tenantId": "292FEC76-5F1C-486F-85A5-09D88096F098",
      "timeStamp": "2016-04-11T13:46:32.708Z"
    },
    "collections": {
      "Customer29Jan16": {
        "meta": {
          "parentreference": "***",
          "pkname": "***",
          "fkname": "***"
        },
        "rowset": [
          {
            "CuId": "",
            "Name": "",
            "Quantity": "",
            "Rate": "",
            "Amount": ""
          }
        ],
        "rowfilter": []
      }
    }
  }
} );
```

In directive i am generating the Binding path using angular foreach

```
bindingPath = "scope.soData.Data.collections.Customer29Jan16.rowset."+index2;
```

Directive Two way binding i am giving like

```
layoutTableCellControlRenderObj.scope={attributeId:'=',controlId:'=',layoutData:'=',pageObject:'=',mapperData:'=', cellControlId:'=', soData:"="};
```

Factory;

```
bosAppModule.factory("layoutRenderingControlsFactory",function($compile){
    var layoutControlsFactory={};

    layoutControlsFactory.ThirdPartyReadOnly=function(controlId, bindingURL){
        console.log("## Create ThirdPartyReadOnly");
        var template='<input  kendo-auto-complete ng-model="bindingURL">';
        return template;
    };  

    return layoutControlsFactory;
});
```

Please help any one to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you parse an already parsed json object?

Comment: @AlonEitan - It's in stringified manner that's why i'm doing parsing there.